# Is there a way to convert a std::string to vector<char> in c++?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, stdvector, stdstring

Is there a simple way to convert a std::string into a std::vector I want to allow the user to input
any length of string and then have a dynamic char array (vector).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>



int main() {
    std::vector<char> word;
    std::string strWord;
    std::getline(std::cin, strWord);
    //What comes next? 
}
```

One thing I tried that did not work is:
`strcpy(word, strWord);`
I get the error no suitable conversion from "std::string" to "const char*" exists.
So since "word" is a pointer to the char array how do I add the string?

Comment: `word` is not a pointer to the char array. `word.data()` is.

Answer (score 7):

You can insert the characters in string to the vector via [`std::vector::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert).

```
word.insert(word.end(), strWord.begin(), strWord.end());
```

To do conversion, the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) of `std::vector` that takes iterators to copy data from is also useful.

```
word = std::vector(strWord.begin(), strWord.end());
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks for the help!